# Get latest object with oldest date from array of objects with date object

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here's what my array looks like

```
[
 { name: "myname", date: dateObj, value: 2 },
 { name: "othername", date: dateObj, value: 3 },
 { name: "newname", date: dateObj, value: 5 },
]
```

Dates are native date objects.

What would be the smartest way to get the one object with the oldest date? Is there a better way than sorting the whole array by looping through?

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: Please clarify `Is there a better way than sorting the whole array by looping through?`. Without iterating through the array, how would you know what's inside it to begin with? It might be that this is the result of some DB query, in which case the best way would be to have the DB sort the returned items.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to iterate the array, and on each iteration pick the object with the oldest date:

```js
const data = [
 { name: "myname", date: new Date(2016, 5, 1), value: 2 },
 { name: "othername", date: new Date(2018, 6, 1), value: 3 },
 { name: "newname", date: new Date(2017, 12, 1), value: 5 },
];

const result = data.reduce((r, o) => o.date < r.date ? o : r);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I was wondering about the efficiency of this, so I wrote a little jsperf for it.  It's about 50% faster than the sort solutions, for obvious reasons, but it's also significantly faster than a simple for loop, which is a little surprising.  https://jsperf.com/min-value-in-array-rntest

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The Array must be pre-sorted. :)

In other words, No. Without iterating the whole Array, there seems no way to find out the Object with oldest date. We need to iterate the Array.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want, if we call your array `myArray`:

```
myArray.sort((objA, objB) => objA.date.getTime() - objB.date.getTime())[0];
```

Comment: OP was asking for a way to do it without sorting.

Comment: Oh OK, perhaps that's what they want. I read it as wanting to do it "without looping through".

Comment: The `dateA, dateB` in `.sort()` contain object. You should use `dateB.date`